Terminal windown will not allow me to respond or continue
I had problems installing a package and was instructed in Terminal that:
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

I then copy and paste this command, and I get a picture of BIOS in the Terminal (shown in the screenshot) but I am not allowed to continue.  The enter key does nothing and neither does my mouse.


Welcome to AskUbuntu! Did you try using the Tab key to navigate to the ""??

That worked! Thank you, now I feel dumb for not thinking of this.....

You're welcome! There's no need to feel that way—I'm glad I could assist.

You have to use the Arrow keys or use the Tab key and Enter on <Ok> when it is highlighted.
But in general, you would better Disable Secure Boot entirely from your system's Boot menu if it's not required. That will be much simpler in the long run, especially when you change the kernel.
